Dividing a 3-digit number by a 2-digit number using 2-digit integer division
I'm looking for an efficient way to divide a 3-digit number by a 2-digit number assuming I can only do 2-digit by 2-digit integer division. Specifically, I'm looking for the integer quotient (and optionally, remainder).
i.e.: I'm looking for Q and R in $(100A + 10B + C) / (10X + Y) = Q + R/(10X + Y)$ assuming I can only perform divisions of the form $(10A + B) / (10X + Y) = Q + R/(10X + Y)$.
I'm posing this problem as a proxy for 48-bit by 32-bit division on a 32-bit microcontroller. This problem has stumped me for a while now, and I think I'm overlooking something, since it can't be that hard.

For example, how would you want to handle $100\div99$?

100 / 99 would be 1 with remainder 1 (Q = 1, R = 1). However with just two-digit division I can't calculate this at once. I expect the solution to look somewhat similar to long division, but I can't do it directly since some of the intermediate results are larger than 2 digits

I'm not sure if that always works, but I can do 100 / 9 (via long division, intermediate results fit in 2 digits) and 99 / 9, and then do (100 / 9) / (99 / 9), but I'm not sure how to deal with the remainders to ensure this doesn't get inaccurate

If "intermediate results fit in 2 digits" is okay, then why not just do $100/99 = 1 + 1/99$ directly?

There is very little point in thinking decimal when the goal is binary and optimized: you are going to get no useful information that way.  OTOH, there are loads of articles about this and similar, e.g. see here: Algorithms for division – part 4 (Segger)  Isn't that good enough?

Thank you for that resource! Judging from how simple it was to derive the other operations, where analogies to decimal arithmetic were very useful and lead to very performant implementations, and I didn't expect division to be so much more complicated.

Analogies with decimal are indeed not useless, after all it's all just positional representations (except these here are not unbounded), but the main point is "optimization" and even "appropriate to a microcontroller with these specific characteristics over this specific range of inputs..."  If that was the question...

Right. The specific microcontroller I'm optimizing for has some characteristics that are hard to describe simply, and I'm usually not bad at optimizing things myself, so in this case I was looking for division algorithms in general so that I can gain general knowledge to apply to specific situations later.
